# Python CSV file read and write with incremental number

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

There is Python CSV read file for input with 2 values. A incremental number and a name.

The records are in millions, most of the time stops in begining.

How to keep a log of incremental number on the write one, so it picks it up where it left off.

```
import csv

data = {}
with open("readfile.csv", "r") as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
        num,name = line.strip().split(',')
        data[num] = name


with open("output.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Number", "Name"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use the Python file seek() and tell() functionality.

You can read the current position offset using tell and store this in another file.

You can then open the file and move to that position using seek.

example functionality would be:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('readfile.csv'):
    with open("readfile.csv", "wb") as read_f:
        with open("position.dat", "wb") as pos_fi:



                read_f.write('aaa,111\n')
                read_f.write('bbb,222\n')
                read_f.write('ccc,333\n')
                read_f.write('ddd,444\n')

                pos_fi.write('0')


data = {}

with open('position.dat', 'rb') as pos_f:
    ps = pos_f.read()
    print 'Position is : ', ps
    p = int(ps)

# open your data file and the position file
with open('readfile.csv', 'rb') as read_f:

        # read the offset position and seek to that location
        read_f.seek(p)
        for line in iter(read_f.readline, ''):
                num,name = line.strip().split(',')
                print num, name
                data[num] = name

        position = str(read_f.tell())

# store your new offset position
with open("position.dat", "wb") as pos:
        pos.write(position)
```

EDIT:

This example now works.

1. If you run the code once it will create the files.
2. If you then edit the 'readfile.csv' and append more lines, and run the code again it again. It will pick up where it left off, and print out the new lines.

Please note to use seek(), you cannot then use readlines() directly on the file object. The trick is to wrap it in an iterator as above.

You would have to adapt your code around this, as I am not sure exactly what you are trying to read and write.

Yes, you could just open in append mode, to write to the end of the file.

Comment: you will need to create a position.dat file initially containing a zero '0'

Comment: Also position.dat should be opened in read mode, example corrected

Comment: position.dat file is now incremented to 22407081, how to use it to pick up where write left off.

Comment: we can just write back Number and Name to output.csv file

Comment: You cant use the file pointer as an interator, it has to be done something like this: for line in iter(read_f.readline, '') - I will adjust example

Comment: can you please adjust the example when you have time

Comment: Updated, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `csvfile` is a file object, so you can use `seek` and `tell` functions to move the cursor on the file. So, when you're done writing, you can get current position with `pos = csvfile.tell()`; then, at next opening, just do `csvfile.seek(pos)`.

Note that you have to open your file in the same mode every time for this `pos` to be usable (binary maybe a good idea).

Another idea is simply to open `csvfile` in append mode: `with open('output.csv', 'ab')`. This writes at the end of the file.